# How to determine when a user's email has been verified by Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-ses

How can I determine if a user has clicked on the link in the verification email sent by Amazon SES?  Looking at the docs, I only see a function to list every verified address.  That seems fairly inelegant and inefficient if there are a lot of validated emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it appears that this is not how I should be using Amazon SES.  It appears from my further research that you are supposed to only verify a few addresses that belong to you and send emails to unverified user addresses.  I will have to implement my own email verification system for the purposes of verifying the address for my own system.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to determine the Email address are verified or not.

```
if (!self::ValidateAddress($address))
$this->SetError($this->Lang('invalid_address').': '. $address);
if ($this->exceptions)
throw new phpmailerException($this->Lang('invalid_address').': '.$address);}
return false;
```